# Separating class methods into separate module in javascript

Tags: reactjs, modularity

I have a method 'joinRoom' which is created using fat aero so I think I don't need to pass 'this' as argument or bind it. This is clear, but I want to store the joinRoom function in another file, but that file (for modular approach and keeping my this file clean) is containing 'this' keyword. How to deal with 'this' keyword in that module ? Check below for the code

main.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        }
        this.socket = null
    }
    joinRoom = () => joinRoom() //this one
    render() {
        return();
    }
}
```

whoisOnline.js

```
whoisOnline = () => {
    sendToPeer('onlinePeers', null, {local: this.socketID})
}
```

I just want to keep all methods in the class in another module but they are involving 'this' keyword, how to handle such situation, please let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and found out a way out, I had to pass 'this' as argument so that the object is available in the function, and then in the function I can utilize it.

main.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        }
        this.socket = null
    }
    joinRoom = () => joinRoom(this) //passed 'this' keyword 
    render() {
        return();
    }
}
```

whoisOnline.js

```
whoisOnline = (object) => { // passed object argument and then used it to access 'this' from the calss
    sendToPeer('onlinePeers', null, {local: object.socketID})
}
```